# How to substitute string in file with the content of other file

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am on `AIX` using `ksh` and I am in need of some help as I am not able to achieve through `sed` or `awk`.
**Template file: (which acts as input)**

```
...  
varchar SelectStmt = 'REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT'
...
```

The value that should be applied *(derived based on the input of the table names in Teradata and comparing the column datatypes of each column respectively and casting them wherever necessary)* in the above is achieved through the awk and re-directed to a file, which has many lines ( >= 100 and <=500 approximately) .

I am reading that file and need to substitute the file content into the above statement of the Template file.  I tried

```
v_select_stmnt=`cat awk_output_file.txt`;   
 sed 's/REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT/"$v_select_stmnt"/g' 
                   Template_file.txt > /directory1/final_script.txt;
```

Even tried with `awk`  as

```
 awk -v a_select_stmnt="$v_select_stmnt" '
 { if ($0 ~ /REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT/) { 
        sub(REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT,a_select_stmnt,$0); }
        print $0 > "/directory1/final_script.txt" }' Template_file.txt
```

**Sample content of awk_output_file.txt:  (May have single quote, semi-colon)**

```
SELECT COLUMN1, CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(10,3)),
       CAST(COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(40)), COLUMN4,
       ....
       CAST(COLUMN600 AS INTEGER) 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_DATE = '2017-01-31';
```

**Expected Output**

```
...  
    varchar SelectStmt = 'SELECT COLUMN1, CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(10,3)),
           CAST(COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(40)), COLUMN4,
           ....
           CAST(COLUMN600 AS INTEGER) 
    FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_DATE = '2017-01-31';'
 ...
```

Can you please help me to resolve this.  As the `select` statement may be large, need to retain the `new-line` characters to make it readable.  If possible can you please post how to resolve this in both `sed` and `awk`.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Template file**

```
$ cat temp 
...  
varchar SelectStmt = 'REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT'
...
```

**Contents**

```
$ cat output 
SELECT COLUMN1, CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(10,3)),
       CAST(COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(40)), COLUMN4,
       ....
       CAST(COLUMN600 AS INTEGER) 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_DATE = '2017-01-31';
```

**Awk**

> Assuming your output file doesn't contain `&` as it will interpreted
>   by the replacement operation

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{r=(FNR>1?r RS:"") $0; next} {gsub(/REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT/,r)}1' output temp
```

**Better Readable Version**

```
awk '  # Here read output file and save contents in variable r
       NR==FNR{
            r=(FNR>1?r RS:"") $0
            next
        }

        # Here read file temp
        {
           gsub(/REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT/,r)
        }1
   ' output temp
```

> If it contains `&` char in output file then,

```
awk 'BEGIN{search="REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT"}NR==FNR{r=(FNR>1?r RS:"") $0; next} s=index($0,search){ $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) r substr($0,s+length(search)) }1' output temp
```

**Better Readable Version**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
        search="REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT"
}
NR==FNR{
        r=(FNR>1?r RS:"") $0
        next
} 
# To take care of & char, credit : Ed Morton
s=index($0,search){ 
        $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) r substr($0,s+length(search)) 
}1' output temp
```

**Both Gives Output**

```
...  
    varchar SelectStmt = 'SELECT COLUMN1, CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(10,3)),
           CAST(COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(40)), COLUMN4,
           ....
           CAST(COLUMN600 AS INTEGER) 
    FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_DATE = '2017-01-31';'
...
```

**Perl**

```
$ perl -pe 's/REPLACE_SELECT_STATEMENT/`cat output`/ge' temp
...  
varchar SelectStmt = 'SELECT COLUMN1, CAST(COLUMN2 AS DECIMAL(10,3)),
       CAST(COLUMN3 AS VARCHAR(40)), COLUMN4,
       ....
       CAST(COLUMN600 AS INTEGER) 
FROM DATABASE1.TABLE1 WHERE COLUMN_DATE = '2017-01-31';
'
...
```

Comment: Works Perfectly.  Thank you Akshay Hegde.